# How do I pass data between flash and javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I have a flash/flex object that is generating xml based on user interactions.
I want to pass an xml string to javascript so that it can make a web service call.

**How do I pass the XML back to Javascript?**

examples:

html:

```
     <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%"
                id="My">
 <param name="movie" value="My.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
      </object>
```

javascript to initialized

```
 var swfVersionStr = "10.2.0";
 var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
 var flashvars = {};

 var attributes = {};
 flashvars.servicePath = "services/";
 flashvars.isSaved = "false";
 flashvars.savedXML;
 var params=   {
            quality = "high";
            bgcolor = "#ffffff";
            allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
            allowfullscreen = "true";
            wmode = "transparent";
        };

  swfobject.embedSWF(
                "My.swf", "flashContent",
                "100%", "100%",
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
                flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Javascript to get XML from flash/flex

```
var flashObject = document.contentWindow.getFlashObject();
flashObject.saveXml();
var xmlFromFlex = flashObject.savedXML; /*This is where I don't know how to get/set*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use **ExternalInterface.call**:

```
import flash.external.*; 
var JSvalue:String; 
JSvalue = ExternalInterface.call('JsTestFunction','Work_Damn_It');
```

More information available [here](http://meshfields.de/externalinterface-call-as3-javascript/)

Comment: I'm trying to get the value from flash, this appears only to be able to pass a value to flash.

Comment: Brian... he gave you the right answer... the 'JsTestFunction' is the name of the function in javascript on your HTML page that you want to call.  ExternalInterface.call will invoke that function on the page and return you the result into flash.

Comment: So, the 2nd parameter('Work_Damn_It') in 
JSvalue = ExternalInterface.call('JsTestFunction','Work_Damn_It'); 
is the 1st parameter's value in the javascript method ?

Comment: How can the first parameter be the value in the javascript method? I thought it is the javascript method.. and `'Work_Damn_It'` is the argument for the javascript function called `JSTestFunction`